# How to disable cache in Vapor?

Tags: vapor, leaf

The changes I make to the leaf templates are not being shown in the browser. I think it's because Vapor is caching the template. How do I disable caching?

Answer (score 2):

In Vapor 2:

```
drop.view.shouldCache = false
```

For Vapor 1:

```
(drop.view as? LeafRenderer)?.stem.cache = nil
```